# Mass Transit Consume Context Message Type is getting changed to Interface Type

Tags: .net, rabbitmq, masstransit

```
public class RabbitMessageConsumer<T> : IConsumer<T> where T : class {   
 public async Task Consume(ConsumeContext<T> context)
    {
       // context.Message type is getting changed to GreenPipes.DynamicInternal one
    }
}
```

Ex.
For **StartCreateCommand** class type, It is getting changed to

**{GreenPipes.DynamicInternal.abc.xyz.ICreateCommand<mymodel_test>}.**

Answer (score 0):

If you are consuming an interface (which in your case, I'm guessing is `ICreateCommand<mymodel_test>`, MassTransit will proxy that interface to avoid creating a dependency on the class (in your case, `StartCreateCommand`). If you want the class in your consumer, consume the class.